# Got error while running POST method WEPAPI

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to run TextToSpeechAPP WebAPI application.I received an error in response body.  Error: Internal Server Error. Can you help me please?

Here is GItHUb link for code and error file. https://github.com/dotnetexpo/TextToSpeechAPP

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServiceName(object lang)` method has a body of `throw new NotImplementedException();`. So, when it is called, it always throws exception.